# Locale from django app not change

Tags: python, django-i18n

I newbie into Django, and I need make a I18N system. I have this url.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
    path(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
]
```

And I made this html to change the language:

```
{% load i18n %}
<form action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="next" type="hidden" value="{{request.path}}" />
    <select name="language">
        {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
        {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
        {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
        {% for language in languages %}
            <option value="{{ language.code }}"{% if language.code == LANGUAGE_CODE %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>
                {{ language.name_local }} ({{ language.code }})
            </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

But when I click in "Go" button, the server response is: Page not found (404),  The current path, i18n/setlang/, didn't match any of these. I stay using python 3.6 and Django 2.0.4.

And I no have idea how can I solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was here:

```
path(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
```

I cut off r'^':

```
path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
```

and works!